# Sum timestamp differences inside a time interval

Tags: sql, firebird

I use Firebird. I want to find the total working time between two dates for a given contact.

There are two tables: WORK and PAY

```
IDWORK | IDCONTACTS | STARTWORK        | ENDWORK
----------------------------------------------------------
 1     | 14         | 04/20/2014 09:02 | 04/20/2014 18:10
 2     | 14         | 04/21/2014 08:41 | 
 3     | 14         | 04/20/2014 08:56 | 04/20/2014 17:01
 4     | 10         | 04/18/2014 09:28 | 04/18/2014 16:22


IDPAY | IDCONTACTS | DATE1            | DATE2            | WORKTIME
--------------------------------------------------------------------
1     | 14         | 04/10/2014 09:02 | 04/27/2014 09:02 |
```

I want to find the total working time between DATE1 and DATE2. I tried to make a trigger on PAY before insert and update:

```
begin
    UPDATE PAY
        SET WORKTIME = (SELECT SUM(DATEDIFF(MINUTE FROM STARTWORK TO ENDWORK))
                    FROM WORK, PAY
                         WHERE WORK.IDCONTACTS = PAY.IDCONTACTS
                         AND (STARTWORK BETWEEN DATE1 AND DATE2)
                         GROUP BY WORK.IDCONTACTS)
        WHERE NEW.IDPAY = OLD.IDPAY;
end
```

but it doesn't work. I also have to check if ENDWORK has a NULL value and raise an error.

Comment: Don't store calculated fields. A trigger can drastically impact performance.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @FreshPrinceOfSO in that it is a bad idea to use a trigger for this. If you really need to store that value, it would be better to precalculate it and then store it, or to calculate it when needed.

Said this, you do not specify your Firebird version, but from version `2.1` onwards you can use the `DATEDIFF` function both in `DSQL`  and `PSQL`.

An example for your case would be following:

```
select DATEDIFF(minute, STARTWORK, ENDWORK) from WORK
```

You can find the doc reference in its corresponding online [Firebird documentation](http://www.firebirdsql.org/refdocs/langrefupd21-intfunc-datediff.html). Also, if you search in this website for `Firebird` and `datediff` you will find some more examples.